# Java Thread with persistent resources

Tags: java, multithreading, shell, concurrency, resources

I have a pool of worker threads (an `ExecutorService`).

This pool is used to run shell commands.

I use a shell (`/bin/sh`) rather than creating a process for the executable directly, because I use shell redirects (`>`) to write the output directly to disk, without having to pass through the JVM, as well as some other niceties.

Spawning a shell process takes 2-3 milliseconds.

I want each thread to keep a shell process to avoid the overhead of starting it.

How do I allow each thread to own a process?

---

I am thinking of using a `ThreadFactory` with thread locals.

```
class ThreadFactory {
    Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        return new Thread(new Runnable() {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh")
            try {
                // store process as thread local here
                r.run(); // then r can access thread local
            } catch(Exception e) {
                try {
                    process.close();
                } catch(Exception e) {
                }
                throw e;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

(Alternatively, I could subclass `Thread` and cast `Thread.currentThread()` to that class in my `Runnable`.)

Is this a good approach to solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the `Process` reference in a `ProcessRunnable` that continuously executes commands. I think is more clear than using a `ThreadLocal` and a `ThreadFactory`. Something like this:

```
public class ShellCommandExecutor {

private int concurrency = 10;
private int capacity = 100;

private ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(concurrency);
private BlockingQueue<String> commandsQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(capacity);

public void start() {
    for (int i = 0; i < concurrency; i++)
        service.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //todo deal with ioexception
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh");
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    try {
                        String command = commandsQueue.take();
                        //todo execute commands using the same process per thread
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}

public void executeCommand(String command) throws InterruptedException {
    commandsQueue.put(command);
}

public void shutdown() {
    service.shutdownNow();
}
}
```

**EDIT**: a solution with thread local that should work easily with cached thread pools:

```
public class ShellCommandExecutor2 {

    //todo limit queue
    private ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public void executeCommand(final String command) throws InterruptedException {

        service.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Process process = ThreadLocalProcessFactory.get();
                //todo execute command
            }
        });
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        service.shutdownNow();
    }

    private static class ThreadLocalProcessFactory {

        private static final ThreadLocal<Process> processThreadLocal =
                new ThreadLocal<Process>() {
                    @Override protected Process initialValue() {
                        try {
                            return Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh");
                        }
                        catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                };

        static Process get() {
            return processThreadLocal.get();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That does work and has the advantage of no unclear casts, etc. The disadvantage is that this really only works with a certain type of thread pool (fixed). If you needed something with the behavior of a cached thread pool, this wouldn't be what you needed.

Comment: You should be able to use a cached thread pool too. Exit the loop if no command is executed in some period of time and the pool will remove the idle thread.

Comment: Anyway, is not a nice solution if you absolutely need a cached thread pool. You also have to submit new tasks if the pool is busy.

Comment: Added a second approach.